# Uniform convergence of a series of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I am reading Chung's book on probability and I've stumbled across this example:

Let $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a set of positive ($\geq 0$) numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n < \infty$ and  $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ an enumeration of the rationals. For instance, we may take $b_n=2^{-n}$.

Consider now $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\delta_{a_n}(x),$$where $$\delta_t(x)= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if }x <t
\\ 1 &\text{if }x \geq t \\ \end{cases}$$

Then the series is absolutely and uniformly convergent.

Since for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $\delta_{a_n}(x) \leq 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|b_n\delta_{a_n}(x)|<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n<\infty$, so from here it follows the absolute convergence but I am having difficulty understanding why it is uniform, I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Since $|b_n \delta_{a_n}(x)| \leq b_n$ you can apply de Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: No test required (and I wonder what makes some users invoke one here): simply the fact that the bound $\delta_{a_n}(x) \leq 1$ does not depend on $x$ implies that the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Hint   :   Weierstrass M-test.